# Abnormal height of fractions after installation of the latest OS Windows

Tags: front-end, output-formatting, stylesheet, windows

After installation of new Windows 10 Enterprise rel 1703, fractions in notebook have become extra high.

For years, I use own external Stylesheet. Before release 1703, all Windows' ans Mathematica versions displayed notebooks as needed. But, in that case,  something went wrong.

Mathematica version: 11.1.1.

Some examples:

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should report it to the official tech support.

Comment: Could it be that some fonts referenced by your custom stylesheet are now missing?  Or perhaps they are accessible under a different name after the upgrade?  Is the problem present with the default stylesheet?  If not, posting the stylesheet may help people track down the problem.